# How can I watch Netflix on 32-bit Ubuntu systems?

Tags: chromium, netflix

With the death of Chrome for 32-bit Ubuntu, is there a way to watch Netflix using Chromium?  The old Firefox/pipelight solution works, but performance is much worse than native Netflix on Chrome.

The solution at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274 has not worked for me.

Updating to 64 bit hardware is not an option for me at this time.

Comment: What do you mean by "death of"? I still see a 32-bit .deb available from http://www.google.com/chrome/

Comment: @IanLantzy: I don't know about that, but read [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued).

Comment: @IanLantzy there will be no future updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firefox 49, it is once again possible to watch Netflix on 32 bit Ubuntu systems.  See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-how-do-i-watch-netflix) for the procedure.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use Chromium, as far as I know, to watch Netflix or Amazon Prime.

You have to use Chrome.
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/10/10/watch-netflix-in-ubuntu-today/

Hulu requires Firefox, since they use some horrible flash DRM, and a little shoehorning with a HAL.
http://itsfoss.com/watch-hulu-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: a) I already use Chrome but it is no longer supported on 32-bit b) I didn't ask about Hulu or Amazon Prime c) other Linux distros have gotten Netflix to work with Chromium.

Answer (score -2):

try useing a user agent switcher, I had everything needed installed but it still did not work until i switched it to look like a chrome browser running on windows. im actualy on firefox and linux ubuntu