# Netflix install

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, system-installation

How can I install Netflix on my device? I have already tried opening the Ubuntu terminal and pasting this :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi -y.
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight.
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

but it is not working and I still have to install silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install google-chrome. You can watch netflix in google-chrome.

Download and install from the following website. Double click the downloaded .deb file and it will install with the ubuntu software center.

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

Answer (score 1):

You can watch Netflix in Firefox without any of that pipelight stuff by following the instructions given in the answer to this question: [Now that I have Firefox 49, how do I watch Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-how-do-i-watch-netflix)