# Netflix just stopped to work on LInux32+firefox

Tags: firefox, chromium, netflix, pipelight

I have been using Netflix on 2 computers for weeks, both with Ubuntu 16, one is a 32 bits computer and the other is a 64 bits. I made them work reading this post: [Now that I have Firefox 49 or higher, how do I watch Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-or-higher-how-do-i-watch-netflix?newreg=3aa9dfe82b54411aaa12a905dd000c4d) and they worked fine but, two weeks ago the trick stopped working on the 32 bits machine (It's still working on my laptop, the 64 bit machine) and I can't understand why. It start to load the video and the message: https://help.netflix.com/es-es/node/23742 does not appear, instead of that, I get the error-code: M7363-1260 which can mean:

(I cant post more than 2 links but googling this error there are three or four branch of it that say maybe something is outdated on my browser (maybe widevine) But I've been trying to update it and I thing it is updated...

Somebody have this problem??

There are more alternatives that work appropriately? I've been trying to install google chrome with wine without exit and to made chromium able to reproduce netflix video with pipelight but same)

I would thanks all kind of help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Netflix should work fine on both Chrome and Chromium, and you dont need wine to install Chrome. Get Chrome 32bits from [google's site](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) , open the file (with Software Installer by default) and it should be installed without troubles.

Comment: There is no Chrome 32 bit at the Google site.

Comment: as Pilot6 said, the problem is that today there is no chrome 32 bits for linux (official) :/

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I haven't been able to fix it yet

Answer (score 0):

Netflix should work fine in Firefox if you're using one of their newer versions which supports CDM (a solution for playing DRM-media through HTML5). (Firefox introducing this made rather big fuzz actually - read [here](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2015/05/12/update-on-digital-rights-management-and-firefox/) or [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm) for more information and tips).

It hard to say why it's not working in your case. Widevine and Adobe Primetime should download automaticly by Firefox I think. You could start by verifying that both Google Widevine and Adobe Primetime is set to "Always Activate":

[image: ...]

Then check that Firefox is set to play DRM content:

[image: Enable DRM Firefox]

Also delete all your cookies and set Firefox to remember history:

[image: Remove all cookies under "remove individual cookies"]

If this doesn't work try to re-install firefox (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox` I guess).

Best of luck!

Comment: that did not work

Comment: This does not work on my 32 bit system.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE: Netflix now supports Firefox on Linux as well. No user-agent spoofing needed.**

As described in this comment on the bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1315978#c11),
you may have to change your user agent to

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36

...and Netflix will work again.

I'm using User-Agent Switcher extension here. The original string mentioned Chrome/40, I think.

Remember it's not a bug in Firefox. It's just that Netflix doesn't officially support Firefox on Linux yet.

Comment: This did not work in my 32 bit system.