# How to run the netflix-desktop app on Lubuntu 16.10

Tags: lubuntu, wine, 16.10, netflix-desktop

I see that until Xenial release of Lubuntu it was possible install netflix-desktop by repository and run it with Wine.
Is it possible also on Lubuntu 16.10 ? Cause I don't find any updated repository to do it.
I can use Netflix on Chrome, but i'm looking for the desktop app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Now that I have Firefox 49 or higher, how do I watch Netflix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828286/now-that-i-have-firefox-49-or-higher-how-do-i-watch-netflix)

Comment: If you have a 64 bit system, you should be able to use either Chrome or Firefox to watch Netflix. If you have a 32 bit system, you will have a lot of trouble.

Comment: I know, and i'm able to do it, but i'm looking for the desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Firefox v52 or higher and you should be able to watch Netflix.

If you really really really want the old netflix-desktop app, direct download it at https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/netflix-desktop_0.8.9-1~ubuntu15.10.1_all.deb

Comment: Yes, but i'm looking for the desktop app!

Comment: I just checked the author's PPA web site, and it looks like Netflix-desktop is no longer available.

Comment: @Mattia  You might check here http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/ and here https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages to download it. Here is the direct link https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/netflix-desktop_0.8.9-1~ubuntu15.10.1_all.deb